# ¿Porque se me cambian algunos valores sin asignarlos? (Solo mostrando en consola)

Tags: javascript, html5, array, motor-de-juego

tengo una duda... resulta que usando JavaScript y la sintaxis de ES6, y dividiendo mi código con ellos haciendo uso de la sentencia export e import, me di cuenta de que por alguna extraña razón, cuando trato de usar una función que retorna un nuevo arreglo y que es el resultado de una pequeña operación entre cada uno de los elementos de un arreglo bidimensional, me di cuenta de lo siguiente:

Tengo objetos creados aparte, tales como piezas, el jugador que controla cada pieza etc. (Ando creando un tetris), la función la ejecuta la clase jugador, y dentro de la clase jugador el constructor tiene un arreglo de piezas inicialmente vacio, la función que intento ejecutar recibe como parametro (Solo como prueba para las primeras dos piezas), una matriz que contiene las filas de la pieza en cuestión  (A su vez, cada fila es un arreglo de numeros), tambien recibe como parametro el lado izquierdo de la pieza en el espacio (como coordenada x), y por ultimo, el ancho de cada "pixel", que conforma la pieza.

Una de las piezas que recibe esta función se vería así tal cual:

```
[
   [0,1,1],                //Pieza S
   [1,1,0]
];
```

Cabe destacar que tengo una constante exportada en otro archivo, la cual la importo en otros, estas son las piezas en su estado original, la constante la renombre a SHAPES, ya que pensé que tal vez era por eso que no servia el código bien sin embargo no es eso..., apartir de SHAPES... en la clase del objeto pieza lo que hago es que apartir de un numero aleatorio entre 0 y 6, el constructor seteara uno de los atributos al que llame: "innerShape" como una copia de la pieza especifica correspondiente al numero aleatorio, esto lo hago con la función map(), entonces innerShape con una de las piezas seria por ejemplo la pieza de mas arriba.

Esta es la función:

```
function toPointMatrix(matrix,left, pixelH){

    let newMatrix = matrix;

    for(let i = 0; i < newMatrix.length; i++){

        for(let j = 0; j < newMatrix[i].length; j++){

            if(newMatrix[i][j] !== 0){

                newMatrix[i][j] = left + (pixelH * j);

            }else{

                newMatrix[i][j] = -1;

            }

        }

    }

    return newMatrix;

}
```

y la forma en como la estuve invocando (de momento solo para probarla para ver el resultado en consola) es esta:

```
 console.log(toPointMatrix(SHAPES[num_aleatorio], 0, 40));
```

Lo raro es que cuando hago un console.log (No asigno el resultado de esa función a ninguna variable ni nada o si??), entonces mi pregunta es...

¿Porqué cuando invoco esta función para ver el resultado en consola, se me cambia el arreglo original si no le estoy diciendo que cambie?

Comment: De hecho en especifico se me cambia solo esa pieza en especifico... .-.

Comment: Tiene toda la pinta de que al hacer `let newMatrix = matrix` estás asignando por referencia el valor de matrix a tu nueva variable. Esto hace que al modificar newmatrix se modifique también la variable original. Prueba a hacer algo como `let newmatrix = Object.assign({}, matrix);`

Comment: Me ha funcionado!, pero que raro... ¿Ha de ser esto un bug del lenguaje de programación javascript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No es un bug, es el comportamiento esperado en JavaScript. Existen dos formas de copiar un objeto, por valor o por referencia:

Imagina que tienes el objeto a `let a = {prop: 'Propiedad'}`. 
Si hiciésemos `let b = a` estamos asignado a `b` la referencia de `a` haciendo que ambos objetos apunten al mismo valor en memoria, por eso cuando modificas uno, lo que haces realmente es modificar el valor subyacente que 'alimenta' a los dos objetos.
Lo que hace `object.assign`, como muchas otras funciones, es crear un nuevo objeto con una nueva referencia, lo que le convierte en un objeto independiente. Si modificas `b` ahora, solo modificaras el valor de `b` que es un nuevo objeto.